# React App class won't render when a child Component changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started to learn React. I'm trying to write a Todo list and so far it looks like: [image: this]

However when I check the box of a Todo, the count of things left to do won't change even when the state of a list of Todos changes (the 'checked' property of a Todo that I just checked change to true)

My App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TaskComponent from "./TaskComponent";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            taskList: [],
            newTaskContent: ''
        }
        this.generateTask = this.generateTask.bind(this)
        this.updateNewTaskContent = this.updateNewTaskContent.bind(this)
    }

    generateTask() {
        if (this.state.newTaskContent) {
            const joined = this.state.taskList.concat({
                id: this.state.taskList.length + 1,
                content: this.state.newTaskContent,
                checked: false
            })
            this.setState({taskList: joined, newTaskContent: ''})
        }
    }

    updateNewTaskContent({target: {value}}) {
        this.setState({newTaskContent: value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{this.state.taskList.map(task => <TaskComponent key={task.id} task={task.content}
                                                                    checked={task.checked}/>)}</ul>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Type your new task'
                       onChange={this.updateNewTaskContent} value={this.state.newTaskContent}/>
                <button name='generateTask' onClick={this.generateTask}>Generate task</button>
                <div>There are {this.state.taskList.filter(task => !task.checked).length} things left to do!</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My TaskComponent.js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class TaskComponent extends Component {
    constructor({task, checked}) {
        super(undefined)
        this.state = {
            taskContent: task,
            checkedState: checked
        }
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    }

    changeHandler({target: {checked}}) {
        this.setState({checkedState: checked})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.state.taskContent}</span>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkedState} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TaskComponent;
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            taskList: [],
            newTaskContent: ''
        }
        this.generateTask = this.generateTask.bind(this)
        this.updateNewTaskContent = this.updateNewTaskContent.bind(this)
    }

    generateTask() {
        if (this.state.newTaskContent) {
            const joined = this.state.taskList.concat({
                id: this.state.taskList.length + 1,
                content: this.state.newTaskContent,
                checked: false
            })
            this.setState({taskList: joined, newTaskContent: ''})
        }
    }

    updateNewTaskContent({target: {value}}) {
        this.setState({newTaskContent: value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>{this.state.taskList.map(task => <TaskComponent key={task.id} task={task.content}
                                                                    checked={task.checked}/>)}</ul>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Type your new task'
                       onChange={this.updateNewTaskContent} value={this.state.newTaskContent}/>
                <button name='generateTask' onClick={this.generateTask}>Generate task</button>
                <div>There are {this.state.taskList.filter(task => !task.checked).length} things left to do!</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class TaskComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor({task, checked}) {
        super(undefined)
        this.state = {
            taskContent: task,
            checkedState: checked
        }
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    }

    changeHandler({target: {checked}}) {
        this.setState({checkedState: checked})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.state.taskContent}</span>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checkedState} onChange={this.changeHandler}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Inside the TaskComponent class I add the function for the event of changing the "checked" state of the check box but somehow the 'taskList' state in my App does not change at all when I try to console.log it. What is my problem here? Be gentle since I'm new to React and Javascript in general.

Comment: All the task have their own state. You are changing the state but not informing the parent.
In parent you have the task list with their status but when you are updating status (checked) you are not informing parent regarding the same.

Comment: State is changed in the `TaskComponent`, `App` component isn't aware that the checked state of any `TaskComponent` has changed. There's no need to save the state in `TaskComponent` component, maintain the state in the `App` component and pass the change handler function from `App` component to `TaskComponent` as a prop. [Demo of fixed code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4upkpu?file=src/App.js)

Answer (score 1):

You are setting state in TaskComponent and expecting it to change the prop in App.js.

Instead of setting a TaskComponents's state when it is checked, I would recommend calling a function passed in as a prop when it is checked, which has its `id` and new value. Something along the lines of:

App.js:

```
// somewhere in your class:
handler(id, value) {
  // set state to reflect changes
}

// in your render()
<ul>{this.state.taskList.map((task) => {
<TaskComponent onChange={this.handler} id={task.id} key={task.id} task={task.content} checked={task.checked} />})}</ul>
```

In TaskComponent.js:

```
changeHandler({target: {checked}}) {
    this.props.onChange(this.props.id, checked);
}
```

I would also recommend making TaskComponent not have state at all, because it seems unnecessary to me.